# Error: building keras model using LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm

I am trying to build a simple LSTM based model but I am getting "can't set attribute error" on the line to add LSTM layer to the model. I am unable to figure the reason as to why this error is appearing. This is the code I am using.

```
left = Sequential()
left.add(LSTM(64,activation='sigmoid',batch_input_shape=(10,look_back,dim)))
left.add(Dense(dim, activation='linear'))
left.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

I do not think there is an issue with code. The version of Keras is 2.0.7 with tensorflow backend. It is difficult to trace the cause of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the latest Keras version: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7736#issuecomment-324989522